# ionic phonegap build and config.xml

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic and Phonegap build service. I also use ionic run [android/ios] to test the app on the phone during development. I notice that the namespace xmlns is different for phonegap and cordova's config.xml file.  Do I need to keep two separate config.xml files, one for phonegap in www/config.xml and another for cordova in root directory? Or is there away to consolidate to one config.xml file?

Comment: Why are you using both PGB and Cordova?

Comment: I like Cordova for development, specially for debugging with live reload.  However, Phonegap build is convenient for building both apps at once.

Comment: Same question, do you have any updates on this ?

Comment: Yes, I placed the config.xml file in my apps root directory for development which includes both cordova and phonegap name spacing and then wrote a small script to copy  the config file into www/config.xml when I was ready to upload my code to Phonegap.  My script also includes, finding and replacing the correct src path to my splashscreen and icons, and also makes a zip file to upload to phonegap. Let me know if this clears up things for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic is a framework that works above the Cordova/PhoneGap framework [and others] and it has many namespace differences I'm sure you've already noticed like 
 `ion-pane` instead of `pane` just to name one of the many.

I feel this is done to make the developer feel like they are working within one framework instead of having to think about understanding angularJS bower, gulp, Cordova all as being different these different frameworks you'd have to deal with (although you are and it would help if you understood them separately) and this is just one of the subtle differences to the ionic workspace.

So no, you don't need to make another one, that is the Cordova config.xml working within the Ionic Framework.

Answer (score 1):

This generates www/config.xml (PhoneGap-build) from existing config.xml (Ionic)

`npm install pgb-config-maker`

Simple and sweet.

Comment: Then `./make-config-xml.sh`
Then `phonegap remote build ios`